# Points along geometry & QChainage unexpected result in QGIS (missing points)

Tags: qgis, qchainage, lines-to-points

I am using Windows 10 enterprise and QGIS version 3.10.1 A Coruna. I have found an unexpected result when I use QGIS to generate points every 160 meters along a road layer (i.e. points evenly spaced along each road in my layer). I find a pattern of what I believe to be aberrantly missing points. I expected the resulting points layer to have points spaced every 160 meters along each and every road.  What results instead is sections of road without points - while there are some points spaced 160 meters apart there are then large swaths (along the same roads) that have no points.

I have used both "points along geometry" tool in the processing toolbox as well as the QChainage plugin - both yield identical results.

I have tried re-projecting my layer with no change in results.  The current projection is EPSG 3857.

Here's a screenshot of the roads with patchy/missing points:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running the Fix Geometries tool (in the processing toolbox) on the lines layer to see if there is some strange issue with the geometries? Also, I assume the sections without points aren't made up of heaps of small lines <160m in length...

Comment: @she_weeds - thanks for your suggestions!  I have tried running Fix Geometries but the results remain the same.  Also, the roads are single lines (not made of small lines).  Do you think it would be appropriate to upload the road layer so that others can look at it?  (Thank you also for including that the Fix Geometries tool is in the processing toolbox - the beginner in me always appreciates including where to find suggested tools!)

Comment: Yes, if you are able to upload the road layer that would greatly improve the chances of you getting an answer as we can then test out various things rather than have a lengthy back and forth in the comments.

Comment: @she_weeds - I have gone down the rabbit hole on where it is most appropriate to upload a file.  It seems that there are differing opinions.  Might you have a suggestion?  Thanks!

Comment: If you have a onedrive or google drive account those are popular options. If you'd rather not have an account maybe wetransfer?